# Access: Filtering form on field - fails when fields contains an apostrophe

Tags: ms-access, runtime-error, apostrophe

I have a filter on a continuous form that uses a Combo Box to select records to match; the code is:

```
Private Sub SelectHospitalCbo_AfterUpdate()

   Me.Filter = "[ContactHospital] = " & "'" & Me.SelectHospitalCbo & "'"
   Me.FilterOn = True
   
End Sub
```

This was working fine until I discovered that if the ContactHospital field includes an apostrophe (e.g. Children's Hospital) I get an error message:

Run-time error '3075':
Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '[ContactHospital] = 'Children's Hospital".

I understand why the error is occurring, but I can't find a workaround.  A recent question on this forum seemed to have a similar problem to mine, but there were no answers.  Does this mean I can't get around it?

In case anyone wants to suggest removing all the apostrophes form the hospital names, I would consider that, but unfortunately this database interacts with a (much larger) database where the hospital names can't be changed and have to match, so that's not an option for me.

Any help from more experiences Access developers appreciated!

Comment: Just in case, you can avoid this problem entirely and it is probably better practice to follow custom.  it is custom for comboboxe's to have 2 columns.  The id, and the description.  the id is the bound column and is invisible because it is set to 0 width.  Then replace all instances  Here: SelectHospitalcbo in the header and ContactHospital in the detail section with the 2 column combo boxes.  When you need the string value for reports and such you just replace the id at that time.

Comment: I've previously used that method, but it caused other problems!  I might have to do a rethink if I can't overcome this issue.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Options:

1. filter by numeric hospital ID instead of its name
2. `"[ContactHospital] = '" & Replace(Me.SelectHospitalCbo, "'", "''") & "'"`
3. `"[ContactHospital] = """ & Me.SelectHospitalCbo & """"`
4. `"[ContactHospital] = " & Chr(34) & Me.SelectHospitalCbo & Chr(34)`

Comment: To answer the question asked.  if you are looking for a quik-fix then you can handle this particular problem by calling Replace and then delimiting the ' properly.  For instance wrap "[Contact... with:
Public Function DelimitApostrophes(stringwithapostrophe As String) As String
DelimitApostrophes = Replace(stringwithapostrophe, "'", "'") End Function
End Function or just wrap with the replace part.

Comment: yes, that really is "'" with "'" but in context it means replace any apostrophes (') with a quoted apostrophe (" ' ".  see replace

Comment: @mazoula, code in your comments show replacing apostrophe with apostrophe - no change.

Comment: @june7, thanks so much for your response, option 2 was the one that worked!